# Why does Rails always display a datetime as 1/1/2000 - with the correct time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

This one is driving me nuts!! The data is getting stored into the db (sqlite3) correctly. However, when I display the date from the record, Rails appears to coerce it to 1/1/2000 - with the correct time. In other words, if I specify this as the date time: December 31, 2009 6:00 PM, sqllite3 will in fact show 2009-12-31 18:00:00. But.... Rails will display the value has January 1, 2000 06:00 PM (keeping the correct time).

I have created virtual attributes to handle date formatting (which appear to work correctly). And, I have set my time zone to:

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

I have to believe this is something simple...It is totally driving me nuts!!

Thanks!

John

Comment: it's probably caused by your virtual attributes. can you post some code?

Comment: I can... Except that this issue was ocurring before I implemented the virtual attributes. Also, the data is being written correctly to the db, so it would appear the setter is working correctly. The getter is using the same techinique illustrated in the railscast.

Comment: As soon as I get back to my pc, I'll post the attribute getter and setter code.

Comment: In my environment.rb file, I have in addition to the time zone entry:


Time::DATE_FORMATS[:event_date] = "%B %d, %Y %I:%M %p"


Here is the virtual attribute getter and setter code:

def Formatted_Eventdate

   if self.Eventdate != nil

      self.Eventdate.to_s(:event_date)

   end   

end


def Formatted_Eventdate=(value)

   self.Eventdate = Time.parse(value)

end

Its as if the date portion of the datetime value is being completely ignored.

Comment: I think the issue is isolated to rails reading the data from the database. Writes to the db appear to be fine. To test, I have this getter code:
def Formatted_Eventdate
   if self.Eventdate != nil
      Time.parse("2009-12-30 22:00:00").to_s(:event_date)
      #self.Eventdate.to_s(:event_date)
 end

With this code, the date displays correctly as:
December 30, 2009 10:00 PM

However, when I comment the that code in favor of reading the Eventdate value fetched in the database, which is stored as: 
2009-12-30 22:00:00

The date is now displayed as:
January 01, 2000 10:00 PM

Answer (score 7):

Well... I found the problem. As it turned out, when rails created the table, it did so using the Time data type. While the date portion of a datetime value will be stored in a time field, it would appear that when reading a time field, rails only considers the time portion.

The fix.. In desperation, I modified the column to be of datetime type. That fixed it.

John

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, using postgres, and thanks user145110 for the suggestion to use the DateTime class instead of Time. That worked for me. I would only add that though I had to change my migration to use DateTime, I was still able to use Time and its methods in tests that compared against DateTime values. In other words, with this original migration:

```
t.time :start_time
```

...and sample assignment using Time:

```
start_time = Time.now.beginning_of_day
```

...it saved ok, but upon reading it later, the year was changed to 2000. Maybe it's an old Y2K bug. LOL. Instead, I simply changed the migration:

```
t.datetime  :start_time
```

..and all my code worked.  Even assignments like this work:

```
start_time = Time.zone.now.beginning_of_year.beginning_of_day
```

I can't help feeling like I missing something, though. Do others use Time to manipulate dates?

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem too. To add some information about the problem:
- In a debug tag (<%= debug object%>), the time and the date was correct, but when using without debug (<%= object.year %>), the year was 2000.

One can expect one of two things:

- attribute:time have only the time (hours,minutes,seconds, etc.), and expect to see that information in the database (without date (year,month and day))

xor

- attribute:time have time and date and that information go to the database (including the casting to the object).

Actually, rails take the two options. IMHO, this is a bug.
Am i correct? or i don't see some point of the rails design?